# Unity IOS app can't use UnityWebRequest to call self signed certificate HTTPS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ssl, unitywebrequest

i used the window and android both can call the self signed certificate HTTPS, but ios not (Unable to complete SSL connection) . Any setting or coding can fix it?

public IEnumerator SetGroupID(int id) {
string url = AppConfig.APIDomain + "/Game/setGroupID/" + id;

```
    Debug.Log("Check color URL : " + url);
    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = UnityWebRequest.Get(url)) {
        // Request and wait for the desired page.
        webRequest.certificateHandler = new WebRequestCert();
        
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        string[] pages = url.Split('/');
        int page = pages.Length - 1;

        if (webRequest.isNetworkError) {
            Debug.Log(pages[page] + ": Error: " + webRequest.error);
            GameMainMenuUI.Instance.OhError(webRequest.error);
        }
        else {
            try {
                Debug.Log(webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                GameMainMenuUI.Instance.OhError("Get Init Data Failed : "+e);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

public class WebRequestCert : UnityEngine.Networking.CertificateHandler {

```
protected override bool ValidateCertificate(byte[] certificateData) {
    //return base.ValidateCertificate(certificateData);
    return true;

    //return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40069824/unitywebrequest-not-working-in-ios). Looks like you have to specify in the Info.plist file that you want to allow "insecure" http connections for the iOS app.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>just-an-example.com</key>
        <string></string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: But i'm connecting HTTPS with self signed SSL

Comment: @sopapok I would suggest that iOS doesn't accept self-signed certificates

Comment: So Apple doesn't allow developer connect HTTPS with self signed SSL, but HTTP is ok?